# Sharing hadith on whatsapp

Tags: hadith

Aoa...
              I regularly share hadiths of our beloved prophet (SAW) on whatsapp to friends. I want to know that what care should be taken in this regard as one of hadith also mean that 'whoever tells a lie against prophet will go to hell". I only share hadiths of bukhari and muslim and try my best to confirm that shared hadees are saheeh. Can i keep sharing hadees of bukhari and muslim or be careful in this matter? Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1):

When you receive a hadith from someone. You better verify the hadith using the reference number. If you found out that it is accurate then you have done your part and you can forward. But dont forward blindly as hadith forwards in whatsapp has no trusted source.